# Is it good idea to use Thread.sleep in AWS lambda java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am using AWS Lambda with Java programming language, due to some requirement I have to give sleep in my lambda function for 2-3 or in some cases upto 12 seconds, is it good idea to put Thread.sleep() in lambda function or it has any technical consequences.

Comment: Can you add a little bit more context? Or perhaps share the code?

Comment: Note that AWS lambdas do have a timeout that you might keep in mind for your use case. if the timeout is reached before your code has finished its processing, the function is terminated.

Comment: What are you waiting for? Can the conclusion of that event not itself trigger a Lambda function (perhaps indirectly through SNS or SQS)?

Comment: Using `sleep` in any async code is a bad idea, why on earth would like to do this? Explain why this is needed.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, I have a situation in my "telecom" based app. in which I am making automated calls to a user and he may or may not pickup the call in given time or any other scenario such as user busy etc, I don't get immediate response from telecom system if the user is busy or no-answer. So, I want to try one more time after putting a sleep of 20 seconds. Maximum retry in my system is only one whatever may be the case, that's why on earth I am doing like this, let me know if you have any better idea.

Comment: Exponential backoff for retry operations, would be a use case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few cases in which doing Thread.sleep is justified.

- Polling every few seconds and checking if certain status, which is not in control of your code has changed. E.g. think of checking if remote process somewhere has finished.
- You want to mock certain piece of code, so that it "takes" more time than it actually does.
- Throttling down piece of code that does multiple operations per second. E.g. requesting multiple resources from a remote server, but throttling down your requests so that you don't overload it.

I'm sure there are quite a few more justifiable reasons. Don't be afraid to sleep your code. Make sure you're sleeping for a justifiable reason. Also make sure your thread model, in which you indeed need to sleep in your code, does not cause [deadlocks](https://www.javahelps.com/2015/06/thread-deadlock.html).

Note that running in AWS Lambda you should optimize your sleeps to as little amount as possible, as you pay for that sweet, sweet CPU time.

Comment: thanks for your reply , yes, in my case their is a certain status which is not in my control as I am making a telecom app. in which I am making an automated call and the end user may or may not pick up or busy etc, so I just want to retry after 20 secs, in the context of my app and the purpose it's solving,  it seems justifiable for me and the payment for lambda is also justifiable to me.

Comment: You have too many responsibilities in your function. The fact you need to pay more is a red flag that you can ignore of course:-)

Answer (score 4):

If your Lambda use a high amount of memory would be better (and cheaper) to start two different Lambda than wait for 12 seconds.

If you have a sort of workflow, or you need to wait for a specific condition you could evaluate the introduction of [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) or (maybe better) send context to an SQS queue with [visibility timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html) set to twelve second. In this way, the second lambda will wait, at least, 12 seconds before starts.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can do whatever you want, in this case you will just pay more :-)

The whole idea of Lambda function is to have a function that takes input and produces output and have a single responsibility, similar to plain old functions.

Let's think why you need to use `Thread#sleep`:

1. You perform action #1.
2. Wait until this action is completed.
3. Perform action #2.

These are 3 different responsibilities. It's too much for any function, including Lambda :-)
Both actions can be separate Lambda functions. With recent addition of Destination, your Lambda #1 can trigger Lambda #2.
In this case there is no need in polling at all.